# Setting active a page(tab) in a notebook of form view

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I'm developing a module for openerp v7.
I've defined a workflow and in my view defined a form with a notebook which contain as tabs as status defined in workflow.
In every tab i've a button which triggers the change of status of the workflow. All of this works like a charm!
The problem I am facing is that when the button triggers the workflow status change, the status changes but the tab marked as active is not changed, as far i know this is the expected behaviour, but i would like to change the active tab when the status of workflow changes and i didn't find any way to do it.
**INFO:** According to the  [DOCS](http://openerp-server.readthedocs.org/en/latest/03_module_dev_03.html) there is a way of doing this with the fields:

> **default_focus:** set to 1 to put the focus (cursor position) on this field when the form is first opened. There can only be one field within a view having this attribute set to 1 (new as of 5.2)

But no way with pages...

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think that making a tab to be active is not the expected behavior with a workflow. Normally, buttons are putted in the header next to the statusbar, and each button have the "states" attribute to define those status they must appear in (according with the "state" field of the model).

If you want to show/hide some information (say field, group, page, etc) according to the workflow status, you can use the "attrs" parameter with the "invisible" option restricted to a domain over a "state" field value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use JavaScript, you can use this to focus a tab page:

```
$('.oe_notebook #ui-id-3').click()
```

Where `ui-id-3` is the 1 based index of the tab page. Here it would be the third page. Works in v8, can't tell for other versions. Hope it helps anyway :)